# Load new HTML file every second with setInterval Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a server running on localhost and I want it to **display a new html file** every second. For example: first 1.html then 2.html then 3.html and so on. This code works when I want to just display 1.html

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream('./states/1.html');

    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    readStream.pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
```

However, when I try using setInterval, I only see 1.html, and it does not change every second to 2.html, 3.html and so on.

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let counter = 0;

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream('./states/1.html');
    setInterval(() => {

        let path = './states/' + counter + '.html';
        readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
        counter++;
    }, 1000);

    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    readStream.pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
```

How do I get Node.js to display a new html file every second?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `counter` variable is inside handler function, which is re-created each time the server handle a request. You must declare it in global context:

```js
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    counter++;
}, 1000);
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let path = './states/' + counter + '.html';
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    readStream.pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
```

Or you can simply do it on frontend (HTML file):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const currentNum = parseInt(window.location.href.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]);
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/[0-9]+/, currentNum + 1);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The first code changes the file readStream points to, but I can only see the change if I reload. Is there a fix?

Comment: Then you need an auto reload mechanism, which is introduced in 2nd code.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring

```
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream('./states/1.html');
```

In setInterval function. 
I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I get ReferenceError: readStream is not defined when I do that.

Comment: Right, my miss.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this from the fron-end side like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   var currentNum = parseInt(window.location.href.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]);
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/[0-9]+/, currentNum + 1);
```

}, 1000);